# Shell-Script: Cronjob vs. user rights

Tags: linux, cygwin, cron

probably an easy question, but I am confused:

When I run the following script manually, it works fine. While I am not running this script as user git but as user X I am able to use the ls and du commands which are applied to git users home directory. 
If I try to run this script in a cronjob, these two commands are not regular invoked, don't know why. The first "extern" invocation of a cmd-file works perfect in both cases and yields a regular output.

What I've noticed: I am just able to run the script as user X with ./runbackup.sh and it is stored in the users home directory.

Cron runs with user X's privileges.

Confusing ... :/ ... any ideas ?

Script: **runbackup.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash

/cygdrive/e/xp-batches/backup.cmd > info.log
echo "### CURRENT HOMEDIR ###" >> info.log
ls -gh --block-size=K /home/git >> info.log
echo "### SIZE ###" >> info.log
du -hs /home/git >> info.log
email -s "Backup Status" dum@dio.com < info.log
```

Comment: A cron job runs with its initial current directory set to the home directory of the owner of the cron job. But what exactly do you mean by "Cron runs with user X's privileges"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better not assume anything about the environment that cron supplies you with. Use full paths:

/bin/ls -gh --block-size=K /home/git >> info.log

instead of just "ls".

Oh and maybe use an absolute path instead of info.log as well.

Comment: It's safe to assume that `/bin` is in the `$PATH` of a process invoked by `cron`.

Comment: ... but in this case yankee was right. I have to specify the entire path to "ls" and "du". Thanks for your help!